# TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined when I use npm

Tags: node.js, npm

An error occurred, when I install mobx-react by npm.

**A complete log of this run can be found in**

```js
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose npm-session bc8c856c7ab7df4b
5 silly install runPreinstallTopLevelLifecycles
6 silly preinstall clock-app@0.1.0
7 info lifecycle clock-app@0.1.0~preinstall: clock-app@0.1.0
8 silly install loadCurrentTree
9 silly install readLocalPackageData
10 timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 12555ms
11 silly install loadIdealTree
12 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
13 timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 60ms
14 silly install loadShrinkwrap
15 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
16 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 12985ms
17 silly saveTree clock-app@0.1.0
18 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
18 verbose stack     at tarballToVersion (D:\node.js\node_modules\npm\lib\install\inflate-shrinkwrap.js:87:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

the string variable given the match method does not exist. Maybe you made a typo. To eliminate errors, you can use the ternary operator

```
someString ? someString.match('your reGex') : null
```

or more simply don't use space and without ':'

```
someString?.match('your reGex')
```

Comment: npm install mobx-react --save

Comment: In my other project(roboat-gallery) is ok, but in this project(clock-app) is bad. Maybe the mistake is the project name.

Comment: clear npm cache
delete package-lock.json.

npm cache clear --force

and try to run the command:

rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clear --force
npm install

Answer (score 0):

clear npm cache
delete package-lock.json.

npm cache clear --force

and try to run the command:

rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clear --force
npm install